# How to get specific data from algolia in angular

Tags: angular, algolia, instantsearch.js

I'm using **algolia** in angular.
I'm trying to get only a specific record from **algolia**.
I have a product_id and want record of that `product_id`
Here is what I have done so far -
.html file

```html
    <ais-instantsearch [conproducts]>
        <ais-configure [searchParameters]="{ hitsPerPage: 1 }"></ais-configure>
        <ais-hits>
           <ng-template let-hits="hits">
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6"*ngFor="let hit of hits">
                    {{hit.name}}
                 </div>
           </div>
           </ng-template>
         </ais-hits>
    </ais-instantsearch>
```

.ts file

```typescript
    const searchClient = algoliasearch(
      environment.algolia_application_id,
      environment.algolia_search_api_key
    );
    
    export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
      productsConfig = {
          indexName: 'products',
          searchClient
      };
    }
```

How to get specific data by id in the **algolia**?
Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to only retrieve a specific record by an attribute from your Algolia index, you can use [`filters`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/filters/). For example, let's say you want to retrieve a record which `product_id` is "abcdef", you can set a filter on your `ais-configure` component like the following:

```html
<ais-configure
  [searchParameters]="{ filters: 'product_id:abcdef' }"
></ais-configure>
```

Note that **your `product_id` attribute must be set in [`attributesForFaceting`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/attributesForFaceting/) for it to be filterable**. You can use the `filterOnly` modifier if you only need to use it as a filter and never as a facet, for better performance. This needs to be done at the index level, either from your indexing code or directly in the Algolia dashboard. You can follow [this guide](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/faceting/how-to/declaring-attributes-for-faceting/) to learn how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

By reading this page of **algolia** documentation:

https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/search/

**.ts file**

```
const searchClient = algoliasearch(
      environment.algolia_application_id,
      environment.algolia_search_api_key
    );
    
    export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {

      hits: any;

      productsConfig = {
          indexName: 'products',
          searchClient
      };

      OnInit(){
           const index = searchClient.initIndex(productsConfig.indexName);

           index.search('query string', {
                    attributesToRetrieve: ['name','firstname', 'lastname'],
                    hitsPerPage: 50,
            }).then(({ hits }) => {
                console.log(hits); // check the console 
                this.hits = hits;
           });
      }
    }
```

Comment: @jMansour Thanks for the answer, but I only want single record of specific product_id. How to do that?